# Field template using Display Suite

Tags: 8, display-suite

In Drupal 7 I could go to any entity's "manage display" and choose "expert" or "minimal," etc.

In Drupal 8, I can see a Twig template for expert, and a Plugin for expert (ex.g.) as well. But how do I get the UI where I can choose 'expert'?

If it's no longer in the UI, how do I implement my own Plugin? How can I write twig for just that field? If I'm doing that, why do I need Display Suite anyway (as I'm just using a one-col layout)? Do I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Please follow the below steps :**

1. Go to  Structure > Display Suite
2. Under Displays please click on settings tab and enable the checkbox named Enable Field Templates
3. Cheerss..now you can select desired templates.